# How to use react test renderer?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, I wrote code for react-test-renderer. However it is giving error. It will be great help , if anyone can give proper example which I can copy past in my system to check it's working. As well as , also tell me benefits of using react-test-renderer.I have gone through React docs. and github but it did not helped me understand topic.My code is as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

function MyComponent() {
   return (
   <div>
      <SubComponent foo="bar" />
      <p className="my">Hello</p>
   </div>
   )
}

function SubComponent() {
  return (
    <p className="sub">Sub</p>
  );
}

const render = require('react-test-renderer');

const stub = createStub();

render(<MyComponent onClick={stub}/>)
  .find(element => element.type === 'button')
  .simulate('click');

assert.ok(stub.called);


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App
```